# Drift Flutter - Get Specific Field Value From Table

Tags: flutter, dart, drift

I am using Drift for the first time and I have been able to create the tables in the database and insert into a table in the database. Now I want to show a field value from the table on my app, for example, a table called Employee that has the employee name in the "name" field, I want to be able to display the employee's name at the top right of the app when they log in. So I want to get the value of the name field for that employee.

How can I achieve this?

A lot of examples I see are for displaying Lists and that's not really what I'm looking for.

I tried to do a get on the table but I don't know how to get the snapshot of the table's data.

```
Future<List<Employee>> getEmployee() async {
    return await select(employee).get();
  }
```

Please how can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

To get a value from `Future` you must use `await`

for more details pls have alook in the [official documents](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

So You can get employees list like this

```
void getEmployees() async {
     final employeesList = await select(employee).get();
  }
```

Where `employee` is the table name.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I eventually found a way to do it. I noticed using ".get()" will always return a list but they have a ".getSingle()" method and you can add a filter before doing the ".getSingle()" and this was what I used. So I did something like this :
`Future<Employees> getEmployee() async {
    return await (select(Employees)..where((tbl) => tbl.id.equals(2)))
        .getSingle();
  }`

This will return that particular record I want and I can now access the other fields like the name, job role, and all that for that particular record. Thank you

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem complete, could you elaborate?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Brendan I updated the answer, hope it's clear now